# Should scene remove layers or layers remove themselves?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, oop, class, design-patterns

This is probably very newbish question but I have a class called Scene which has an array of a class called Layer. Each layer is like an interface layer or game screen layer and scene calls update&draw function of layers etc..

My question is when adding or removing those layers, should it be 
**scene.addLayer(layer);**
or
**layer.addToScene(scene);**
?

Both looks fine by me but is there any rule in OOP?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question has to do with programming with the Java programming language. Why the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: I don't know much about ActionScript, but on review of tag use on stackoverflow, the [tag:actionscript] tag is often used together with the [tag:javascript] tag an almost never with the [tag:java] tag. I'm betting that you meant to use the [tag:javascript] tag, but I don't know enough about this to confidently edit your question in this way. If I am correct, you'll want to edit your tags so as to get the right folks looking at your question.

Comment: I use several languages including java but not sure what tag I should put in this case as it was a general question for all OOP languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a *problem* but instead I think you want an opinion...

I'm not aware of any OOP rules discouraging either of them, but I think `scene.addLayer(layer)` would be the best because it makes the most sense. Let's say you have a jar that you put coins in. Would you say `coin.addToJar`? ***No***, it does not make sense! The coin does not put itself in the jar! You have to tell the jar to accept the coin. Even with Java GUI's, you have `Container.add(Component)`.

(P.S. This question does not necessarily have to be in the Java tag, it could apply to any object-oriented language.)

Comment: That makes sense. Come to think of it, ActionScript also uses container.addChild() for adding display objects to display container.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that @Java has written a lovely answer, and i will provide you with another view. If your layers are going to be garbage collected (deleted) when the scene that owns them is deleted then i would go with `Scene.AddLayer(Layer)` because it gives Scene some ownership semantics over the layers. On the other hand if those layers are going to be shared by different scenes i would go with `Layer.AddToScene(Scene)` for the opposite reason. Of course this is just a personal style and it is not based on any software engineering principles.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Originally I was doing Scene.addLayer but wasn't really sure if I was doing something wrong.